# Can you use multiple phones to control the same Android TV unit?

Tags: android, android-tv

If I have a Nexus Player, and connect to it with more than one phone ([Using Android TV Remote Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tv.remote&hl=en)), is it possible to distinguish between each controlling unit in the code?

(It would make for a cool way to do multi-player games without the need for expensive game pads - friends can just use their phones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Each input device is given a unique identifier when connecting to an Android device (including the Nexus Player). Refer to the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice.html#getControllerNumber()). I believe there are already multiplayer games on the Nexus Player which accomplish this (seen [here](http://phandroid.com/2014/11/11/android-tv-games-without-gamepad/)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I cant upvote due to my profile being new though.

Comment: If you think it's correct, you can still give the check mark :)